# How customer's contacts related to ATM?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Melanie: You don't have an ATM.
>
> Dorothea: Them things. **Russ won't get one because you lose personal
>   contact with customers.**
>
> Melanie: Yes. That would be tragic.

I understand the sentence, but I can't find any connection between customer's and ATM. Dorothea says ATM would let Melanie to lose personal contact with customers. My doubt is Why would a ATM does such things to her?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean by *connection*? An ATM is a machine that eliminates much of the interfacing between the customer and the bank's employees.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I made my question clear.

Comment: Dorothea says **personal contact** which requires at least two people, here, customer and employee.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Please post answer in its section.

Comment: Your question is not about English, and so I will leave it as a comment.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but it seems extremely likely that Dorothea works at a bank (where Russ is the branch manager). Given that OP *must* have been watching the film in order to post this question, I'd say the "connection between (**bank**) customers and ATM" ought to be blindingly obvious from context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the context of the above sentences were a bit wider this would be easier, but I’m guessing that ATM in the above sentences is referring to a bank ATM (Automated Teller Machine).  In this context, installing an ATM would allow customers to do their banking without speaking to an actual bank teller.  If Melanie is the bank teller, then she would not be speaking to customers who use the ATM, and would lose personal contact with them.

Additionally, it sounds like Melanie’s last comment is meant to be sarcastic.  She believes not needing to talk to customers would be a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it may be a metaphor, where ATM refers to "any of their customers". They want to rip off their customers? it's just a guess.